# LINQ TO SQL Inheritance Mapping With Typed Tables in DataContext

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hey guys I had a working LINQ2SQL system with typed tables, but now that I've tried to add inheritance mapping between 2 class, I am getting a error creating an instance of DataContext. Error is "input string in incorrect format". I'm guessing theres some conflict with having typed Tables in my Datacontext class, and the mapping I've put in place.

Heres a shortened version of my code

```
public class DataAccessHelper : DataContext
{
    public static DataContext db;
    public Table<CronJob> CronJob;
    public Table<SongCronJob> SongCronJob;

    public DataAccessHelper(string connection) : base(connection) { }

}

[Table(Name = "cron_jobs", )]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "CJ", Type = typeof(CronJob))]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "SCJ", Type = typeof(SongCronJob))]
public class CronJob //Instantiated by any cron job run
{
    //IsDiscriminator = true, 
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDiscriminator = true, Name = "id", IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "cron_jobs_songs")]
public class SongCronJob : CronJob
{
}
```

I should also say, the CronJobs classes has a few mapped properties (which actually only exist in the subclass's SQL table, I'm assuming this is OK. (I.E i only want to declare those properties on superclass one as all child cron jobs will share them. (And i will never instantiate the superclass)

Code that is now throwing the errror:

```
DataAccessHelper db = new DataAccessHelper(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataDB"].ConnectionString);
```

Stack trace:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9594283
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +46
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +385
   System.Data.Linq.DBConvert.ChangeType(Object value, Type type) +3236
   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedRootType..ctor(AttributedMetaModel model, AttributedMetaTable table, Type type) +408
   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaTable..ctor(AttributedMetaModel model, TableAttribute attr, Type rowType) +97
   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaModel.GetTableNoLocks(Type rowType) +216
   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaModel.GetTable(Type rowType) +184
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(Type type) +51
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.InitTables(Object schema) +180
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping) +269
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection) +44
   Helper.Data.DataAccessHelper..ctor(String connection) in C:\Users\william\Desktop\Stuff\Important Notables\Subversion Dev\Projects\CodenameDiddy\helper\Data\DataHelper.cs:20
   CodenameDiddy.masterpages.Cronxxx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\william\Desktop\Stuff\Important Notables\Subversion Dev\Projects\CodenameDiddy\http\masterpages\Cronxxx.master.cs:32
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's becoz of type mismatch between InheritanceMapping code and discriminator column ID one is string and the other is int